# KVM and port security

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

In my test environment I get everything working perfectly the way I want it. Running Cloudmin KVM instances over a bridged adapter. Then when it comes time to install at the data center I hit a brick wall. They have port security turned on which only allows one MAC address over the network port. Since I only have 2 interfaces I need to run several KVM instances (10 or more) with each assigned their own static public IP. I don't have a range of IPs either. I was assigned specific ones.

Is there a way around this where I can assign each KVM instance it's own IP but only use one MAC address? Keep in mind this needs to be KVM via Cloudmin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Cloudmin personally, but the network engineer in me says this is probably not possible. If you're using a bridged adapter, all the machines are effectively separate entities, with their own MAC/IP combo, and this is how ARP is able to locate them. Pushing them all on one MAC address wouldn't work in a traditional setup, and I don't see how it could here, unfortunately. You will have to ask them to either turn off port security for your port, or add all of your VMs to the trusted MAC list.

Alternatively, using a NAT bridge instead of a bridged adapter should also work.